# How can I make my led turn on for 1 second then turn off for 1 second?

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller

I am learning embedded and I had the simple task of lighting up a led, but also i want to implement a timer that turns the led on for a second and then turns it off for another seconds(and so on), but i am not sure how to do it. I am working on a ATmega324PB microcontroller using the IAR Embedded Workbench. Here is my code:

```
include "iom324pb.h"
#include <ioavr.h>

#include <intrinsics.h>

void set_output(int pin)
{
  DDRC |=(1<< pin);
}

void set_pin(int pin)
{    
    PORTC |=(1 << pin);  
}

void turn_off(int pin)
{ 
  PORTC &= ~(1 << pin);
}

int main(void)
{     
 set_output(7);
 
 while (1)
 {
   set_pin(7);
  
   turn_off(7);
 }
  
}
```

I have searched on the internet but the codes I've found were far too complex for my understanding.I've also tried using the __delay_cycles(1000); function but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: 1000 cycles doesn't seem to be very long. I doubt you would even notice it. You should dig into the examples regarding interrupt handling and timers for your micro

Comment: You're calling *turn\_off* just after *set\_pin*. Maybe the latter does something (turns on the led) but you don't give it enough time in order to actually see it. add a *sleep* between the 2.

Comment: For the delay function to work, you need to define the system clock as a macro. Did you do this? Please show your attempt to use such a function as a [mre]. Are you considering to use the [AVR Libc](https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/)?

Answer (score 2):

[ATmega324PB](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/ATmega324PB) has an internal 8MHz RC oscillator, while the code has no explicit initial process for the peripheral of MCU. Then, assuming ATmega324PB runs with a main clock of 8MHz by default, so a `__delay_cycles(1000);` would wait for about 125uS and some more. Instead, `__delay_cycles(8000000);` or a finite-loop, e.g. `for(i=2000000;i>0;i--);`, might work.

Suggestion: Try to use its internal Timer to implement the functionality of delay. The application note [AVR130: Using the timers on tinyAVR and megaAVR devices](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/application-notes/an2505)  would be a viable reference.